# Image Thumb Previews for SharePoint

Tags: c#, jquery, css, sharepoint-2010, sharepointdocumentlibrary

Is there a way to generate an image preview of images added into a SharePoint list?

The scenario is the following:

For image files (.jpg, .tif, .png) that are added into a SharePoint document library which are then listed or viewed via "list view web part on another page" when the user hovers over any of the image files a popup window or anything similar should be displayed showing a preview of the image. Is this possible to achieve in SharePoint and how would this be done.

Would css alone achieve this, or will it require c# code behind.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SharePoint picture libraries ? There you got thumbnails, preview and so on.

Or you could make an custom solution using ex.  jquery fancybox .

I would suggest that you use standard SharePoint or connect the hover effect on the picture library on your own list.

see
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/working-with-sharepoint-picture-libraries-HA001123335.aspx

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olaGyX4g2Cc

Comment: OK thanks for the suggestion, I have devised a solution with jquery